# Zoom H4N Audio recording for android videos?

Tags: audio-recording, stereo, zoom-h4n

I have seen how to connect the USB B mini to the USB C port for audio recording.  However since the Zoom draws power from the USB, I would like to use a stereo jack connector from the phone's USB C (has a stereo converter) ton the Zoom.  Thoughts?

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is here - your post has been flagged as needing details or clarity.

Comment: I'd consider asking the manufacturer for their recommendations.